# how to deserialize json to alpacajs specific format

Tags: alpacajs

Like how we have Serialize API available for translating the data in the form to JSON data, do we have a deserialize api CALL to translate the data from json into alpaca specific JS ?
We have a requirement to translate the JSON data into a AlpacaJS specific JSON . is there a easy way to do this ?

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried.

Comment: not tried it yet but wanted to check if this is planned as a alpaca update